# syncfusion ASP.NET Core Chart control Disable Click event

Tags: model-view-controller, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am fetching my Monday to Friday Class data from WEB API and assign to **VIEWBAG**, which display in the syncfusion CHART. Now during run time when I click on the **"Monday To Friday"** it shows me the **BLANK** chart. I want to **DISABLE** THE CLICK on **"Monday To Friday" TEXT in Graph**.

```
<ejs-chart id="container" title="Daily Class Taken" width="60%">
        <e-chart-primaryxaxis valueType="ClassData"></e-chart-primaryxaxis>
        <e-series-collection>
            <e-series dataSource="ViewBag.dataSource" fill="#FFFF00" name="Monday - Sunday" xName="DateModified" width="2" opacity="1" yName="ViewDuration" type="@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column">
            </e-series>
        </e-series-collection>
    </ejs-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you to disable **toggleVisibility** for legend to achieve your required scenario. Please check with the below sample and snippet.

```
<ejs-chart>
    <e-chart-legendsettings toggleVisibility="false"></e-chart-legendsettings>
</ejs-chart>
```

**Sample :** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ToggleVisibility-1693683250.zip

**UG :** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/chart/legend/#series-selection-on-legend